# Area of polar plot

Tags: plotting, computational-geometry

How can I plot and find the area of this region?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Polar plots trickery**

```
plot = Show[PolarPlot[{Sin[f], Sqrt[3] Cos[f]}, {f, 0, 2 Pi}], 
  RegionPlot[
   Sin[ArcTan[x, y]] > Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] < 
    Sqrt[3] Cos[ArcTan[x, y]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}], 
  Epilog -> {Text[Style["II", 30], {1, -0.5}], 
    Text[Style["III", 30], {1, 0.5}], 
    Text[Style["reg", 30], {0.25, 0.3}]}]
```

[image]

The area of the bigger circle (let's call it region `I`) is composed of `II`, `III` and `reg`. So, the area of `reg` is the area of `I` diminished by the area of `II` and `III` (note the careful choice of angles):

```
a1 = Area[
  CoordinateTransform["Polar" -> "Cartesian", {r, f}], {f, -Pi/2, 
   Pi/2}, {r, 0, Sqrt[3] Cos[f]}]
a2 = Area[
  CoordinateTransform["Polar" -> "Cartesian", {r, f}], {f, -Pi/2, 
   0}, {r, 0, Sqrt[3] Cos[f]}]
a3 = Area[
  CoordinateTransform["Polar" -> "Cartesian", {r, f}], {f, 0, 
   Pi/2}, {r, Sin[f], Max[Sin[f], Sqrt[3] Cos[f]]}]
```

> (3 π)/4
>
> (3 π)/8
>
> 1/12 (3 Sqrt[3] + 2 π)

Hence

```
reg = a1 - a2 - a3 // FullSimplify
```

> 1/24 (-6 Sqrt[3] + 5 π)

Answer (score 9):

```
r = RegionIntersection[
   Disk[{0, 1/2}, 1/2],
   Disk[{Sqrt[3]/2, 0}, Sqrt[3]/2]
   ];

Area[r]
```

> `1/24 (-6 Sqrt[3] + 5 \[Pi])`

```
rp = RegionPlot[r];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Could u show this solution with Wolfram | Alpha quer?

Comment: @BayasgalanDamdinsvren This is a site for showing how to use *Mathematica*, and not for W|A. Try http://community.wolfram.com

Comment: @C. E. where is the Rho=Sin[Phi] and Rho=Sqrt[3]Cos[Phi] in your script?

Comment: @Bay, C. E. elected to directly represent the disks as regions instead of explicitly writing down their polar equations.

Answer (score 1):

Just for another way. Adding the area of the parts from the 2 circles:

```
sol = Solve[(x - Sqrt[3]/2)^2 + y^2 == 3/4 && 
    x^2 + (y - 1/2)^2 == 1/4, {x, y}];
r1 = 1/2;
r2 = Sqrt[3]/2;
a1 = VectorAngle @@ (# - {0, 1/2} & /@ ({x, y} /. sol));
a2 = VectorAngle @@ (# - {Sqrt[3]/2, 0} & /@ ({x, y} /. sol)); 
area[r_, t_] := r ^2 (t - Sin[t])/2
res = Simplify[area[r1, a1] + area[r2, a2]]
```

yields:

```
1/24 (-6 Sqrt[3] + 5 π)
```